# chained hash tables not giving proper output

Tags: c, arrays, hash, linked-list, hashtable

My current issue is that I have troubles finding the places where my code breaks. I get output, there are no compiling errors, but the output is wrong and incomplete since it looks like it doesn't output everything it should.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TABLE_SIZE 8

typedef struct stItem item;
struct stItem {
    int key;
    item *next;
};

void init(item * H[]) {

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        H[i] = NULL;
}

int h(int k) {

    // this does not work at all (but from exercise description), replaced with temp code

    /*
    int m = TABLE_SIZE;
    int A = ( sqrt(5.0) - 1) / 2;

    return m * (k * A % 1);
    */

    return k % TABLE_SIZE;
}

void insert(int key, item * H[]) {

    int keyHashed = h(key);

    if (H[keyHashed] == NULL) {

        printf("hashkey: %d (%d)\n", keyHashed,key);

        item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
        temp->key = key;
        temp->next = NULL;

        H[keyHashed] = temp;

        free(temp);
    }

    else {

        printf("hashkey: %d (%d) (duplicate)\n", keyHashed,key);

        item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
        temp->key = NULL;
        temp->next = H[keyHashed]->next;

        while (temp->key != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->key = key;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
}

int search(int key, item * H[]) {

        int keyHashed = h(key);

        if (H[keyHashed] == NULL)
            return -1;

        else if (H[keyHashed]->key != key) {

            item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
            temp->key = NULL;
            temp->next = H[keyHashed]->next;

            while (temp->key != key && temp != NULL)
                temp = temp->next;

            if (temp->key == key) {
                free(temp);
                return keyHashed;
            }

            else {
                free(temp);
                return -1;
            }
        }

        else
            return keyHashed;
}

void printHash(item * H[]) {

    printf("\nTable size: %d\n", TABLE_SIZE);

    int i = 0;

    for (i; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {

        if (H[i] != NULL) {
            printf("i: %d          key: %d",i,H[i]->key);

            if (H[i]->next != NULL) {

                printf("chaining print\n");

                item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
                temp->key = NULL;
                temp->next = H[i]->next;

                while (temp->key != NULL) {
                    printf(" -> %d", temp->key);
                }

                printf("\n");
            }

            else
                printf("\n");
        }

        else
            printf("i: %d          key: none\n",i);
    }
}

void test() {

    // a)
    int array[7] = {111,10112,1113,5568,63,1342,21231};

    item *h[TABLE_SIZE];
    init(h);

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 7; i++)
        insert(array[i], h);

    // b)
    printHash(h);

    // c)
    printf("Search result for 1: %d", search(1, h));
    printf("Search result for 10112: %d", search(10112, h));
    printf("Search result for 1113: %d", search(1113, h));
    printf("Search result for 5568: %d", search(5568, h));
    printf("Search result for 337: %d", search(337, h));
}

int main() {
    test();
}
```

And here is the current output:

```
hashkey: 7 (111)
hashkey: 0 (10112)
hashkey: 1 (1113)
hashkey: 0 (5568) (duplicate)
hashkey: 7 (63) (duplicate)
hashkey: 6 (1342)
hashkey: 7 (21231) (duplicate)

Table size: 8
i: 0          key: 5568
i: 1          key: 5568
i: 2          key: none
i: 3          key: none
i: 4          key: none
i: 5          key: none
i: 6          key: 21231
i: 7          key: 5568

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 0.572 s
Press any key to continue.
```

As you can see, the search results aren't displayed at all and the hash table is not at all correct. There seem to be numbers where they shouldn't be according to the output and it's not outputting any of the duplicates in the same index at all.

EDIT: The current state of the `insert()`function:

```
void insert(int key, item * H[]) {

    int keyHashed = h(key);

    if (H[keyHashed] == NULL) {

        printf("hashkey: %d (%d)\n", keyHashed,key);

        item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
        temp->key = key;
        temp->next = NULL;

        H[keyHashed] = temp;
    }

    else {

        printf("hashkey: %d (%d) (duplicate)\n", keyHashed,key);

        item * temp = malloc(sizeof(item));
        temp->key = NULL;
        temp->next = H[keyHashed]->next;

        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        item * temp2 = malloc(sizeof(item));
        temp->next = temp2;
        temp2->key = key;
        temp2->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger, keeping an eye on your data as you do?

Comment: Well, the thing is that at my level of expertise I wouldn't know how to use a debugger nor what to do with its output, providing I could get it to work. I'm still very much a beginner in all of this.

Comment: If you are going to be doing this sort of thing beyond this project, it is a very good skill to learn. Failing that, `printf` is your friend. Use it to determine whether things are happening as you think they should. Print out different messages in different sections of code, list variable values, traverse data structures if you have to.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be that you `free(temp);` after inserting it into `H`. When you insert it, you aren't inserting a copy of the temporary entry, you are inserting a pointer to it. When you then `free` the memory that pointer points to, it can get overwritten by any later memory allocation.

Yes, the manual memory management in C is a pain.

And then you might want to look at your handling of duplicates again. You are creating a new entry and set it up, but you are never actually entering that entry into `H` so duplicates are ignored.

Comment: Thanks. That was definitely part of the problem. I have made the change and updated the original post. There is still problems though.

Comment: @enenra Plese do not edit your question in a way that the answer someone wrote doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: the idea was that the previous versions are still easily visible in the edit history. I presume that's not enough? As for the code: I think I know what you're referring to but I'm confused as to what I'd have to do to fix this. I don't free that temp so shouldn't it just stay there? Or do I have to create a separate struct to "leave there"?

Comment: @enenra You would not `free` an entry of the hashtable unless you either explicitly delete it, replace it with something else or discard the hashtable as a whole.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I'm confused as to what is going wrong with adding duplicates as linked list items behind existing items.

Comment: @enenra As I said, you are never actually entering the new entry into the hashtable. Look at the code to handle duplicates again. At no point does `temp` get inserted into the linked list. The problem might become more obvious when you try to rewrite the code to **first** find the end of the linked list and **then** create a new node and append it to the end of the list.

Comment: FWIW, the code looks like it was originally designed to insert the new item at the beginning of the linked list, which is simpler than adding it at the end.

Comment: @user3386109 As far as I understand, we have to insert it at the end. I'm trying to adjust the code to do that at the moment.

Comment: @Philipp I have made some adjustments to the code but am unsure where to put them to show people considering I'm not supposed to change the original post.

Comment: @enenra you could *amend* your original question or ask a new question altogether.

Comment: I ammended the original post. Does that fix the issue of the new items not actually being linked to the existing entries?

Comment: @enenra It can't be correct - you are writing two mallocs when you only create one new entry. But seriously, we already wrote 13 comments to this one answer. It is time to write a new question, because your current problem isn't your original problem anymore.